# How to manage certificate, truststore and keystore key files in a Java project

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, keystore, cloud-security

I am accessing a database in the cloud. In their "How To" page, it is mentioned that you can put these ca.pem and service.key files in your local path.

In my Spring boot project, in application properties, I have put :

```
ssl.truststore.location=/Users/Me-myself/local/path/keys/client.truststore.jks
```

I have used commands to crate the stores and I can access my remote cloud database.

My question is, How can other people who will clone my project be able to run it successfully in their local machines?

Is it a good practice to embed these files into my spring-boot project?

Answer (score 0):

Put the truststore file in the resource directory of the Spring Boot project.

All files in the resource directory are added to the JAR file when it is built
and will be in the classpath.